# Linear dependence under transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear map $f:\mathbb{R}^6\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$ and I'm asked to show that if $u$,$v$ and $w$ are linearly dependent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^6$ then also $f(u),f(v),f(w)$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ are linearly 
dependent.

Since they are linearly dependent :

$C_1(u) + C_2(v)+C_3(w)=0$ and
$\exists C_i,s.t:C_i \neq 0$

Also:

$\left|\begin{matrix}
   u_1 & v_1 & w_1 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
      u_6 & v_6 & w_6 \\ 
 \end{matrix}\right|=0$

But I'm not sure how to proceed, if I could somehow show that $[f(u)|f(v)|f(w)]$ has $0$ determinant but I don't know what the linear map is. How can I show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use determinants for this.

Since $u,v,w$ are linearly dependent, then there are $a,b,c$ not all zero, such that
$$
au+bv+cw=0
$$
so
$$
f(au+bv+cw)=f(0)
$$
and then, by linearity,
$$
af(u)+bf(v)+cf(w)=0
$$
Therefore…

Comment: Thank you but how do I know the $a,b,c$ of the second equation are not all $0$?

Comment: @ενοίδαότιουδένοίδα They're the same as before, aren't they?

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase my question, how do I know that $a,b,c$ don't change in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: @ενοίδαότιουδένοίδα Sorry, but this is nonsense: just apply linearity. I added a line. Note that $a,b,c$ are *scalars*.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant thank you!